# Command in VIM to replace something by the same character many times

Tags: vim

Is there a vim command to replace something (a word, an inner object, a motion, etc) by a character but as many time as there are character to replace.

Exemple: 
The cursor is at the beginning of the word `foo`
I want X and replace `foo` by `XXX`.

(I don't want to have to count the number of letter, so `3rX` is not a valid answer)

**I don't want a script or a mapping, I just want to know if there is already a command to achieve that**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this works:

verX

Of course the 'e' could be a different movement command.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, the visual mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the cursor at the beginning of a word then you can do the following:

- <kbd>v</kbd> Go in visual mode
- <kbd>w</kbd> Select the word ( here you can use other [motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word-motions) too)
- <kbd>r</kbd> replace with
- <kbd>X</kbd> here you puts the character you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

`verX` in normal mode to replace a word with Xs

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [Colin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384543/377270), but using the "inner word" selection lets you be less picky about the cursor position:

```
viwrX
```

visual inner word replace X

Comment: I'm sad that I learned about `iw` and `is` and `ip` many years after learning the basics -- I don't think of them as readily as I should.